# How to configure Teams personal app to allow site to use SSO

Tags: microsoft-teams

I like to create a Teams app that opens our Help Desk portal (it's an external site),
and pass my O365 creds through via SSO.

When I access the site in Edge, the site comes up to its login screen where the user can click an SSO login button, or enter non-SSO (local) credentials.

Clicking the SSO button redirects the user to login.microsoftonline.com and allows the user to auth (if not logged in already in the browser), and proceeds to the page in the site that we use.

I created a personal Teams app, registered it with AAD, got its App ID and Application URI for SSO
and configure it in the app in the Developer portal.

When I test the app, the home page of the site displays in the personal tab I created, but when I click on the sites SSO Login button, the tab goes blank.

Using the Teams dev kit and debugging it, I see that when I click the SSO Button it redirects to login.microsoftonline.net and displays an error: "login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect"
I'm assuming this is the clickjacking protection kicking in?

My question is, can someone direct me to an example of how to pass SSO info through when the site has multiple login options,(local and SSO) and SSO has to be selected?

Sorry if this isn't clear.

Thanks in advance

Tried creating a second personal app tab with just https://login.microsoftonline.com as the URL with a scope of personal. When clicking on that tab, nothing displays, so I'm assuming it's the clickjacking thing again?

Comment: Are you looking for the same?
Sample Link- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp